# Calculation in field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus

I am little bit rusty in field theoretical calculations. I am reading the book by Altland *Condensed matter field theory* 2nd ed. On page 15, he derives the funcional derivative of the action:

$$
S[\phi+\epsilon\theta] - S[\phi] = \int_Md^mx(\mathcal{L}(\phi+\epsilon\theta, \partial_\mu\phi+\epsilon\partial_\mu\theta - \mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi))\\ \stackrel{?}{=} \int_M d^mx \left[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi^i}\theta^i + \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\phi^i}\partial_\mu\theta^i \right]\epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2).
$$

Naturally, my question is how to obtain the second equality.

Comment: Look for any derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equations. Typically in mechanics books this is done for only one variable (time), but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're just Taylor expanding $\mathcal L$. Hopefully you agree that

$$
f(x+\delta x, y+\delta y)=f(x,y)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\delta x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\delta y + \ ...
$$
Similarly, we have
$$
\mathcal L(\phi+\epsilon\theta,\dot\phi+\epsilon\dot\theta)=\mathcal{L}(\phi,\dot\phi)+\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial \phi}\epsilon\theta+\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial \dot\phi}\epsilon\dot\theta +\ ...
$$

where I've simply made the substitutions
\begin{align}
f\leftrightarrow\mathcal L\\
x\leftrightarrow \phi\\
y\leftrightarrow \dot\phi\\
\delta x \leftrightarrow \epsilon \theta\\
\delta y \leftrightarrow \epsilon\dot\theta
\end{align}

If you plug in this expression for $\mathcal L(\phi+\epsilon\theta,\dot\phi+\epsilon\dot\theta)$ into your expression for the integral, you get the final result.